# How to reset FreeBSD install?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, configuration

I was upgrading FreeBSD on my virtual host, from 10.0 to 11.1. While upgrading from 11.0 to 11.1 I was confronted with a large amount of files that had to be diffed and edited. I tried my best, failed, and now can't login to my server.

Using `ssh -vvv` I can see the following happening:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "xxxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxxx [xxxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ruihpacheco/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
```

Is there a way to just force FreeBSD to accept whatever factory settings it comes with on 11.1? Basically wipe everything out and let me reconfigure from the start?

**Update**

My host comes with 10.0 only so a new clean install would involve me upgrading from 10.0 to 11.1 all over again. I'm already at 11.1, I just want it to work.

Comment: But I don't know what else is broken. And the file doesn't exist.

Comment: some info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321972/153195 see the similar problems

Comment: During the upgrade on the server freebsd-update alters /etc/ssh/sshd_config on your FreeBSD server.
It tries to be smart about it but it has messed up my config more than once. It is a simple text file which is easy to read and correct.

Comment: Do you have physical access to host, if so replace /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the disk with a version from a FreeBSD 11.1 installation. That should let you back in - but who knows what else is broken if you did not complete the merge fully.