# scp does not work but ssh does

Tags: ssh, scp

My local machine and remote machine are both connected to the same network i.e my Android Phone hotspot. I can connect to remote machine by ssh but, the problem is when I am trying to copy some files into remote machine, I am facing error messages, the strange thing is that yesterday `scp` was working, but today `scp -v file.txt root@191.168.43.85:/root` giving following error message:

```
Executing: program /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ssh host 191.168.43.85, user root, command scp -v -t /root
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 191.168.43.85 [191.168.43.85] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
lost connection
```

Here is content of `~/.ssh` folded from local machine

```
# ls -la .ssh
total 12
drwx------  2 u0_a334 u0_a334 4096 Jul 25 12:33 .
drwx------ 36 u0_a334 u0_a334 4096 Jul 25 12:05 ..
-rw-------  1 u0_a334 u0_a334    0 Jul 25 12:33 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 u0_a334 u0_a334  175 Jul 25 11:51 known_hosts
```

I checked `/etc/hosts.deny` all things are commented so it is not culprit.

Here is content of known_hosts file from local machine

```
# cat .ssh/known_hosts
192.168.43.85 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBB4scw5vCUl2dssTS97+5QhiMBIk+/Tc15LoqAoS05i99jMOwRwyRpoNcKTk52d5hprkI7ECIGC9Qrh1KcIniFM=
```

I think it is not duplicate of this [Trying to SSH into server and getting key_load_public: No such file or directory error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory)

Because my situation is a little bit different, as I can still control my remote machine, by means of `ssh root@192.168.43.85` . By the way I tried all solutions from [Trying to SSH into server and getting key_load_public: No such file or directory error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory)

**Edit**

After generating private keys everything is working fine but still I am confused why scp was working without private keys.

Comment: Post output of the command: `ls -la /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/`

Comment: Let's see if ssh still works. Does `ssh root@191.168.43.85 echo hello` work?

Comment: There is already a solution available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to SSH into server and getting key\_load\_public: No such file or directory error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @sai sasanka I don't think it is duplicate bcz my ssh is working

Comment: @Mark Plotnick not working here is output of your command `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` but It is working `ssh root@192.168.43.85` and I can control remote machine

Comment: @Bob you can check now

Comment: @Aux Could you post output of `ssh -vvv root@191.168.43.85`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `scp` tries to use ssh private keys which aren't in place - there are no nesessary keys `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa` inside directory

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/
```

since the command

```
ls -la /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/
```

returns

```
total 12
drwx------  2 u0_a334 u0_a334 4096 Jul 25 12:33 .
drwx------ 36 u0_a334 u0_a334 4096 Jul 25 12:05 ..
-rw-------  1 u0_a334 u0_a334    0 Jul 25 12:33 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 u0_a334 u0_a334  175 Jul 25 11:51 known_hosts
```

There are two possibilities to fix the error.

First possibility is to copy requried private keys (possibly one of them or some of them) `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa` to directory `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/` .

Second possibility is to instruct explicitly `scp` to use some definite private key with `-i` (identity_file) option, i.e.

```
scp -i /path/to/id_rsa file.txt root@191.168.43.85:/root
```

If you don't know where are you identity files stored, but `ssh` works (as noted in OP), execute `ssh` with `verbose` option and find in connection log path to identity file used by `ssh`:

```
ssh -vvv root@191.168.43.85
```

Comment: Wouldn't `scp` use password authentication, just like `ssh` would, if there are no private keys available?

Comment: @Kusalananda I hope ssh password authentification has been disabled  according to best practice recommendation. Let's wait and see reply from OP author.

Comment: @Bob ssh is also trying to search private keys in same directory like scp but then ssh is using password method so after generating private keys now scp is working again

Comment: @Aux Is your `scp` working already now after private keys were generated? Has the problem gone away?

Comment: @Bob problem gone away :) but still I am confused why scp was working without private keys but now not

Comment: @Aux Try to move temporarily private keys to another directory and try `scp` with `PreferredAuthentications=password` and `PubkeyAuthentication=no` options, i.e.: `scp -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no file.txt root@191.168.43.85:/root`