# Can't ssh into my server after ubuntu release upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, upgrade

Today I did a ubuntu release upgrade on my server from 16.04 to 18.04. After the system rebooted, my ssh connection to the server (From putty) failed with "Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection". Right now I only have access to the server filesystem through the Virtuozzo power panel. In my `/var/log/auth.log` there are no entries with of my login attemps. Nmap still shows an open port at 22. Right now I have no Idea where to look for causes for this problem. Through Virtuozzo I may start a repair mod, which starts a temporary setup with the original file system in a `/repair` directory. Where can I look for causes of this problem?

Comment: Is this a problem like https://www.joho.se/2016/05/13/ssh-keys-are-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts-help/?

Comment: Check your .ssh/authorized_keys and make sure your public key is in there else you may have to add yours.

Comment: authorized_keys is still intact and correct. The linked problem is different as the author did get a password prompt. Here the server does not even get to the part of authorization but cancels the connection before.

Comment: Try doing `ssh -v <user>:<host>` from the command line. It would print a line like `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`. Can you print the output of the command.

Comment: You can also do `ssh -G  -vvv <username>@<host>` as per the discussion at https://serverfault.com/questions/717129/how-to-show-the-host-configured-default-ssh-configuration

Comment: That is the result that I get https://gist.github.com/Tyde/911bca9fed4f4b70aa3052f9ab76ef0d The server closes the connection after SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT

Comment: Lookup this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467312/ssh-connection-reset-by-ip-port-22-ubuntu-16-04. Very close to what you are seeing. It may be related to you private key file permissions. Once you login to your server, you should be able to see your ssh logs using the command `sudo journalctl -u sshd`

Comment: Note that what you see is not ssh's fault,  but a network problem.  An SSH server would close gracefully during session start-up,  and the message would read "Session closed by remote host."