# Transferring Files from Remote Server to PC using SCP

Tags: scp, remote, file-transfer

I am trying to use the command,

```
scp -r mylogin@myremote.server.fr:/pathto/my/workfolder/ C:/MyPC/Downloads/
```

to copy `workfolder` to my PC. However, although some files have been downloaded successfully,  the download is getting interrupted with the message,

```
Connection reset by (IP address) port 22
Broken pipe
```

I am using a Windows machine and using this command in the `CMD` window. I have used this before but never faced this issue. Recently I shifted to a new place with a wifi connection. Previously I used a wired connection. Where is the issue? The issue is something like described here but I didn't get the solution.

[ssh - Connection reset by [ip] port 22 (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467312/ssh-connection-reset-by-ip-port-22-ubuntu-16-04)

The `nmap myremote.server.fr` returns,

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( nmap.org ) at 2021-03-20 19:15 W. Europe Standard Time 
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 6.34 seconds.
```

The `nmap -Pn myremote.server.fr` returns,

```
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower. 
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( nmap.org ) at 2021-03-20 19:16 W. Europe Standard Time RTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds, decreasing to 2.0 
RTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds, decreasing to 2.0 
Nmap scan report for myremote.server.fr (IP address) 
Host is up (1.1s latency). 
Not shown: 999 filtered ports 
PORT STATE SERVICE 
22/tcp open ssh 
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 616.70 seconds.
```

Looking forward.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this information. Comments are very hard to read and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: The output for the nmap command has been added to the question.

Comment: I have arranged the output for the nmap above. I am not sure about the location of the server but I have added a query. What has that got to do with the connection breaking while downloading my folders in the server?

Comment: Oh. Are you getting some files transferred, but then it breaks?

Comment: Yes, this is what is happening. Is there a way to ensure despite an interruption all folders will be properly downloaded?

Comment: Could it be unreliable WiFi? That's what you have described as being the changed factor

Comment: It's particularly happening for this IP. I have tried other websites and it seems normal. Tried also with a wired connection and there is not much of a difference.

Comment: Is it possible that downloads from a certain country or geographical location can show such slowdowns? I tried downloading stuff from other websites and there is no issue with that.